# Timeout error handling using utl_http in oracle

Tags: web-services, plsql, oracle11g

one help please ie

when we use the UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout (180);

how to handle the situation after timeout , for example the ws did not respond for more than 180 sec.
Then we should handle that.
in my requirement.

we should get the timeout error; and insert it into a sepearte logging table the error message.

can you please help me on this

```
 UTL_HTTP.set_wallet (l_chr_wallet_path, l_chr_wallet_pwd);

  -- Initializing Request.
  UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout (l_chr_timeout);

  l_request :=
     UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST (URL            => l_chr_ws_url,
                             METHOD         => l_chr_method,
                             http_version   => l_chr_http_version);

  -- Setting Authentications.
  UTL_HTTP.set_authentication (l_request,
                               user_id,
                               password);

  -- Setting appropriate Headers.
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_request, l_chr_usr_agnt, l_chr_usr_agnt_val);
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_request, l_chr_conn, l_chr_conn_value);
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_request,
                       l_chr_content_type,
                       l_chr_cnt_type_value);
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_request,
                       l_chr_content_lgth,
                       DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH (l_chr_req_txt));
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_request, l_chr_trnsf_enc, l_chr_trnsf_enc_val);      

  l_num_req_bdy_lgth := DBMS_LOB.getlength (l_chr_req_txt);
  l_num_chnk_offst := 1;

  WHILE (l_num_chnk_offst < l_num_req_bdy_lgth)
  LOOP
     IF l_num_chnk_offst + l_num_bfr_size >= l_num_req_bdy_lgth
     THEN
        l_num_chnk_lgth := l_num_req_bdy_lgth - l_num_chnk_offst + 1;
     ELSE
        l_num_chnk_lgth := l_num_bfr_size;
     END IF;

     DBMS_LOB.read (l_chr_req_txt,
                    l_num_chnk_lgth,
                    l_num_chnk_offst,
                    l_chr_buffer);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
        'Before WS Write : ' || 'l_chr_buffer : ' || l_chr_buffer);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
        'Before WS Write : ' || 'l_num_chnk_offst : ' || l_num_chnk_offst);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
        'Before WS Write : ' || 'l_num_chnk_lgth : ' || l_num_chnk_lgth);

     UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT (l_request, l_chr_buffer); -- DATA => l_chr_req_txt);
     l_num_chnk_offst := l_num_chnk_offst + l_num_chnk_lgth;
  END LOOP;

  l_response := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE (l_request);      

  -- Print the Response.
  LOOP
     --UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE (l_response, l_chr_buffer, TRUE);

     UTL_HTTP.READ_text (l_response, l_chr_buffer, 32000);
     l_resp_clob := l_resp_clob || l_chr_buffer;
  END LOOP;

  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE (l_response);
  DBMS_LOB.close (l_resp_clob);
  DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_resp_clob);
  p_o_status := 'S';
```

Comment: What is your specific question - how to write an error message to a table? Please show your code.

Comment: @OldProgrammer
Yes . i want to write the error message in a log table.
Code:

Comment: Go read up about pl/sql exception handling and writing to a table using an autonomous transaction.

Comment: Hi @F0cus, did you got manage the timeout to the second that you set in  set_transfer_timeout?